# How to insert the up and down arrows in a selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to insert the up and down arrows next to the `Maximize` and `Minimize` options in `choices`. So I would like to leave it as follows:

Maximize ↑

Minimize ↓

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
       column(
          width = 6,
          selectInput("maxmin", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize"),
choices = list("Maximize " = 1, "Minimize" = 2), selected = "")
        )
      )),
      
    mainPanel(
      
    ))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Adding fontawesome icons to your dropdown may help you, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68509516/7669319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use unicode

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          selectInput("maxmin", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize"),
                      choices = list("Maximize \u2191" = 1, "Minimize \u2193" = 2), selected = "")
        )
      )),
    
    mainPanel(
      
    ))
  
)
```

-testing

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did the same thing you did but mine didn't show up. Strange no? I inserted the image in the question of how it turned out.

Comment: @Antonio I changed only that part as I showed and nothing else

Comment: @Antonio can you show `packageVersion('shiny')`.  I used `1.6.0`

Comment: Yes, It is: `packageVersion('shiny')`
`[1] ‘1.6.0’`

Comment: @Antonio I am not sure about the issue.  I tried on Rstudio in macOS and it is working correctly for me

Comment: No problem, I'm seeing what it could be. Because I used exactly your code. I'll try restarting RStudio to see.

Comment: @Antonio Can you show your `sessionInfo()` in your post

Comment: @Antonio I am guessing that your issue is a case of encoding.  Can you try the soluiton [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324872/rstudio-not-picking-the-encoding-im-telling-it-to-use-when-reading-a-file)

Comment: appears when I run the code: `Warning messages:
1: unable to translate 'Maximize <U+2191>' to native encoding 
2: unable to translate 'Minimize <U+2193>' to native encoding ` Now that I've seen it. It's a coding issue, right?

Comment: @Antonio can you try the solution in the link I shared in comments above for encoding issue

Comment: I will check now

Comment: @Antonio This is actually an encoding issue and it is not related to the solution I posted.

Comment: I agree, therefore I will accept your answer.